# Calling a sql stored procedure from excel using a service account in the connection string

Tags: sql, excel, vba, connection-string, service-accounts

I am having a hard time calling a stored procedure in SQL using service account credentials in my excel application. I am specifying the userid and password in the connection string in the following format.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SomeServerName;Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=ServiceAccountId;Password=ServiceAccountPassword
```

I have also tried the following different formats to make it work somehow by trial and error.

```
Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SomeServerName;Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;Trusted Connection=No;User ID=ServiceAccountId;Password=ServiceAccountPassword


Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SomeServerName;Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;Persist Security Info=No;User ID=ServiceAccountId;Password=ServiceAccountPassword
```

The issue is it is still taking the user id of the logged on user (windows login), and not the user id of the service account. I am not sure how to get around this issue in an excel app based on macros.

The below code shows how i am trying to establish the connection and storing the data in a recordset

```
Sub EstablishConnViaServiceAccount()

Dim objMyConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim objMyCmd As ADODB.Command
Dim objMyRecordset As ADODB.Recordset

Set objMyConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objMyCmd = New ADODB.Command
Set objMyRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo ErrLabel

    objMyConn.connectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SomeServerName;Initial Catalog=SomeDatabase;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=ServiceAccountId;Password=ServiceAccountPassword"
    objMyConn.Open

    Set objMyCmd.ActiveConnection = objMyConn

    objMyCmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    objMyCmd.CommandText = "[spGetSomeData]"

    objMyRecordset.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    objMyRecordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    objMyRecordset.Open objMyCmd

    Set objMyCmd = Nothing
    Set objMyRecordset = Nothing     
    Set objMyConn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any kind of help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Post the full code - not just the connection string.

Comment: I have posted the subroutine in which i am trying to establish the connection via service account. Please have a look and let me know what i am missing or doing wrong

Comment: Create an UDL file and Test your connection then copy the Connection string from the file if a connection is established sucessfully

Comment: @SivaprasathV Actually i can test it directly via SSMS but this is a Local Service Account i can't login with it using normal SQL Server Authentication.